# WPF Grid with child. How to bind child IsEnable to parent row

Tags: wpf, grid, parent-child, telerik-grid, wcf-binding

I'm new with WFP, and I try to work with `Telerik` grid and childs for each row.
This is my xaml:

```
<telerikGrid:RadGridView x:Name="rgvProductsMatricolari" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerProducts}" ... >
    <telerikGrid:RadGridView.ChildTableDefinitions>
    ...
    </telerikGrid:RadGridView.ChildTableDefinitions>
    <telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="SelProductsMatricolari" Header ="" Width="Auto" TextAlignment="Center">
            <telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkProductsMatricolari" Style="{StaticResource chkStandard}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        </telerikGrid:GridViewDataColumn>
        <!-- other columns -->
    </telerikGrid:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerikGrid:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=rgvProductsMatricolari}" Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=rgvProductsMatricolari, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}">
                <!-- the grid -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikGrid:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate>
</telerikGrid:RadGridView>
```

As you can see, I'd like to disable and hide the child `Grid` if the `checkbox` (`IsSelected` for model) of parent row is selected.
I've some problem with `{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=rgvProductsMatricolari}` becouse click on `checkbox` do not select the row.

How can I bind child Grid "`IsEnabled`" property to "`IsSelected`" property of parent Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:GridViewRow}}" ... >
```

Comment: Yes, adding first this line: `xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"`